# Column delimiter error in SSIS while trying to import CSV file to mysql

Tags: ssis, columndefinition

I got the example data like this. Since the 1st row is column name, and I get the error on the 3rd row: "The column delimiter for column 'ShipName' was not found". I tried to open it in excel and find out the problem in about the ShipName of this row, which the ShipName is 0-, the column delimiter can not work so well

```
"RX_MMSI","IMO_Number","Call_Sign","ShipName","MMSI","Navigational_Status","ROT","SOG","Position_Accuracy","Longitude","Latitude","COG","True_Heading","Time_Stamp","Ship_and_Cargo_Type","Reference_Position_A","Reference_Position_B","Reference_Position_C","Reference_Position_D","Fixing_Device","ETA","MAX_Draught","Destination","DTE","Record_Time"
"994161823",,,"SHENQ LONG NO.66    ","416006056","15","128","5.6","1","121.846033","24.753658","333","511","11","30","8","4","2","2","1",,,,"0","2022-01-01 00:08:12"
"004161814",,,"0-"","412441717","15","128","2.4","0","120.829527","26.493880","191.4","191","21","0","0","0","0","0","0",,,,"0","2022-01-01 00:08:21"
```

How can I solve this, and maybe they are some similar problem as this case

Pleas help

Comment: It's not because it's `0-`. it's because it's `0-"`. Note there are two closing quotes in this data item. Importng this kind of data is a lot easier if you use a tab delimited file, without text qualifiers (which in your case is the `"` symbol). Do you have any control over the format this is created in? You could also try specifying _no_ text qualifiers and remove the `"` symbols afterwards.